# Adding vertices to a filled face?

Tags: vertices

I have a hoodie with two cat-headed holes punched in. If i just fill a face in it, i get it filled up but with no vertices at all inside the shape which will mess up my weight painting. I'd like to fill them in and also have vertices inside.

[image: Photo]
[image: Filled in]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the knife tool to create vertices inside of it, press K and start creating the vertices, conecting it with the outside ones. Other option is to select this face and press CTRL + T to triangulate it and make more vertices on it, but the knife tool is better